# In Gtk, what's the difference between a TreePath and a TreeIter?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

I've been learning to use `TreeView`s, and these two types are often used for accessing a particular row of a tree. I don't really understand the difference between the two. My code is working--I convert back and forth between the two based on a function's required parameters--but not based on any real understanding of why.

What is the difference between these two types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a detailed explanation of this **[here](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?tut-treeview-model-reference)** from the Gtk folks. Essentially, a `TreePath` is a way to describe the logical position of a row in the model. For example, the `TreePath` "5:3:2" means:

- look at the children of the sixth [5] node at this level; then,
- look at the children of the fourth [3] node at this level; then,
- look at the third [2] node at this level

This exactly describes the one node you're after by drilling through each tree level.

By comparison, a `TreeIter` is a more direct reference to the node in question, more like a pointer to a specific node.